# Fixing magic_quote affected data

Tags: php, mysql, magic-quotes, magic-quotes-gpc

I've got a CMS to fix some issues. Since the hosting service has enabled php_magic_quotes in the server their database contains content with slashes. Once I got the project I requested the hosting party to switch off the magic_quotes and the issues isn't available anymore. However I need to fix existing affected data because of magic quotes. Is there any mysql or php command where I can use to fix these. Some records badly affected. As an example I can see something like this in the database  `you\\\\\\'r` Appreciate any suggestion to fix these existing data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`stripslashes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) to unescape your data:

```
var_dump(stripslashes("you\\\\\\'r")); // string(6) "you\'r"
```

Comment: Great... Thanks. I never thought this will help. I will try this by writing a script and will update you. Thank you for the answer.